# How to convert UTF-8 strings to ascii in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following string:

`String data = 'árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép'`

I want it to be this:

`'arvizturo tukorfurogep'`

Is there a way to do it in Dart?

Thanks

Comment: This translates to "flood resistant mirror drill" according to google translate... what does that mean?

Comment: It's a test my python (2) teacher taught us to test whether it prints the Hungarian letters.